# name lookup of 'iter' changed for new ISO 'for' scoping

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile the two files below, but get an error message from the compiler: gcc 4.3.3 (Linux)

The error is in the line signed with: LINE WITH ERROR

What I'm I doing wrong, how should I change it?

Luis
...............................

```
$ g++ -c b.h b.cpp 
b.cpp: In function 'void calcularDesempPop(std::vector<Individuo, std::allocator<Individuo> >&)':
b.cpp:19: error: name lookup of 'iter' changed for new ISO 'for' scoping
b.cpp:17: error:   using obsolete binding at 'iter'
```

...............................
FILE: b.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "desempenho.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Individuo {
    vector<double> vec;
    double desempenho;
};



void calcularDesempPop(vector<Individuo>& pop) {
    for (vector<Individuo>::iterator iter = pop.begin();
                    iter != pop.end(); ++iter);//LINE WITH ERROR
        iter->desempenho = calcularDesempenho(iter->vec);
        cout << endl;
}
```

...............................
FILE: b.h

```
#ifndef GUARD_populacao_h
#define GUARD_populacao_h

//#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include "cromossoma.h"

struct Individuo {
    vector<double> vec;
    double desempenho;
};


void calcularDesempPop(vector<Individuo>& pop);

#endif
```

Comment: Note that, while the extra `;` is the cause of this error, if you want the `cout` statement to be part of the loop you're going to need to put those two statements in curly braces (that is,  `{}`s)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> $6.5.3/3 - "If the for-init-statement
>   is a declaration, the scope of the
>   name(s) declared extends to the end of
>   the for statement."

Therefore iter cannot be accessed outside the for loop scope. Check the semicolon immediately after the for loop. Most probably you did not intend it that way.

Comment: No, I didn't intend to use the ';'.
Thank you all.

Luis

Answer (score 9):

You left a **semicolon** after for():

```
for (vector::iterator iter = pop.begin(); iter != pop.end(); ++iter);
```

which means the next line is not a part of the loop body, and `iter` is undefined in it.

Answer (score 1):

always avoid

```
for(..;..;..); { }
```

Comment: I would use a word stronger than *avoid* here ;)