# Changing name look up?

Tags: c++

I've the following codes, and the compiler says that "name lookup of 'i' changed...". 
Setting -fpermissive, it could pass the compiler...

```
for (i=1;i<MAXINUMBER-1;i++)
{
    for (j=i;j>0;j--)
    {
        if (a[j]>a[j-1])
            {
                temp=a[j-1];
                a[j-1]=a[j]; a[j]=temp;
            }
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

But I don't think I have changed the 'i'...
So anything I have missed?
Thank you guys very much...

Comment: Where are these variables declared?

Comment: which line is it complaining about?

Comment: unrelated but `else break` make the algortihm incorrect.

Comment: Please post the entire method, per comment from Oli the declaration of i and j are going to be relevant to the issue. This is also a possible related question (certainly in terms what the error message is referring to) --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601154/name-lookup-of-iter-changed-for-new-iso-for-scoping

Comment: unrelated, but couldn't you  std::swap(a[j], a[j-1])  ?

Comment: I didn't expect you guys to reply so quickly~~ thank you very much! As for the swap function... uh, maybe write it in this way is simpler... and for the 'else break',  I didn't get it why it's wrong(it's a sorting algorithm), we can discuss on that... As for my question, the answer below is good. Sorry if it made you confused that I didn't put up the previous loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple,

```
//the int i declaration below is like it's within the {} block
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //do something
}

//i is out of scope here, you can't use i any more, u must redeclare
//int i = 5; //ok!
//for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) //ok!
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) //no, you can't do this
```

Two way to solve your problem,

One, put i declaration outside

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Two, declare i again

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Comment: Hmm... his code example sure makes it look like 'i' is in scope when it hits the second for()... It's not what you are saying is wrong but I don't think this applies to the code that's been listed. Trying out the sample code on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php and it will compile and run (baring the else break weirdness).

Comment: I think user was suggesting that `i` was declared in a previous `for` loop (since the OP hasn't edited to show us declaration of `i` yet). But I think if `i` was out of scope it would have a different message along the lines of "I don't know what `i` is". We're only guessing though til we get more info from the OP.

Comment: Thank you guys... It's helpful. Indeed, there is another loop using 'i' before this loop. As a learner, I don't know that the previous loop will matter so I didn't put it on. Sorry if it has made you confused. I also don't know that in a for loop, the declared 'i' will be destroyed after loop. Again, thank you very much!!